# Is there any way to extract/omit certain characters from a variable for a readable version?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to extract characters from a variable/array so that it tweets/shares/emails in a readable format

I.E The code I have is like this:

```
var currentQuote = "\"Silence is better than Bullsh!t\"\n - Unknown"
```

I want to be able to have my Share function Tweet/Email the currentQuote. However, It emails it with the characters `\` and `\n` included, Is there anyway?

I can set a rule to extract these when sharing/tweeting it?

I.E) It would tweet something like this:

```
Silence is better than Bullsh!t - Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the if-statement and you can omit any chars from the string

```
func removeSomeChars(a: String) -> String {
  var final: String = ""
  for character in a {
    if character != "\"" && character != "\n" {
      final += String(character)
    }
  }
  return final
}
```